# Moving intrinsic database to external database

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I have implemented permission using intrinsic database.

But as that database is in my bin folder,I have not checked in that.

Now my questions that

How my team member (taking latest from TFS) will be able to use the roles/users and permission I created?

Can I generate insert script(including data )by attaching the intrinsic data base and create a new database in sql server

and change my web config?

Or what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit F5 during the development of a light switch application an intrinsic database is created for debugging purposes only. This database is not check in to source control (TFS for example).
When you activate security (forms or Windows authentication ) the tables of the asp.net membership are added to the intrinsic database.
But again, only for debugging purposes.

When you deploy your application to the cloud (azure) or on premises (IIS Server and SQL SERVER) the asp.net membership tables are recreated. These tables contain the information about users, roles and permissions assigned to roles. After deployment the security administrator has to define the roles and the permissions assigned to the roles.

In Lightswitch for Visual Studio 2013 there is the possibility to add a database project to your solution and associate it with the main Lightswitch project. In the database project's scripts you could initialize entities so that every time you deploy your Lightswitch application, this data, gets created. But the disadvantage of this approach is that you are accessing the database directly and not through the middle tier, so it could be possible to initialize your entities (and roles and permission assignments) in an invalid state.

Another approach could be to initialize your entities (also your roles and permission assignment to these roles) in the _initializeWorkspace method of your startup screen, checking first if the required roles and permission assignments exist and if not create them through the security data context.

Hope this helps.